# ASIHTTPRequest always use defaultresponseEncoding insted of Encoding mentioned in the XML file

Tags: ios, xml, encoding, asihttprequest

Problem is that, while downloading an XML file using ASIHTTPRequest it use default response encoding instead of using the encoding in "encoding" attribute in the header.

The class use header information to set the responseEncoding to the particular encoding in "Charset". So the class works well in case of a HTML page as it include the encoding type in the header itself.

The default encoding is  NSISOLatin1StringEncoding but the encoding in the attribute is UTF-8, which render response string like "funciÃ³n" instead of "función".

So I want responseEncoding property of request(ASIHTTPRequest) to be set to the encoding type in the XML file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASIHTTPRequest does not parse your xml file, it decides the encoding based solely on the contents of the http headers.

Use request.responseData to get the raw data instead and do the conversion to string yourself.

Comment: yes, i get response string from raw data and encode it as u said, but while passing the data to NSXMLParser i got some mismatches . Instead of "información" i got informaci\u00f3n through the delegate

Comment: @VigneshKumar That seems correct, if this is NSLog output. \u00f3 means this character: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/f3/index.htm - or if you're actually getting the 6 raw characters \, u, 0, 0, f and 3 then you have a bug in your code somewhere :)

Answer (score 2):

If it is your `NSLog` statement output then it is correct and the `ASIHTTPRequest` class is working correct only